# How do I use CSS selectors in JSoup to select all elements containing images, including in a data-src (HTML5 dataset) attribute?

Tags: java, html, css-selectors, jsoup

I'm trying to use JSoup to parse any web page and programmatically identify the elements that are content blocks, defined as any element that occurs multiple times and contains text, a link, and an image. All was going well until I got to http://fansided.com/. Images on this page shows up not in an `<img>` tag, but in an attribute like `data-background="http://cdn.fansided.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/314/files/2015/01/8O7hjxQ-268x150.png"`.

Is there a way to use a single CSS selector (perhaps a regex?) that will select all elements containing images, regardless of their type?

Comment: Not quite what you want, but all you need to do is select anything having a `data-background` attribute which ends with an image file extension , eg `Document.select("[data-background~=.*(\\.png|\\.gif|\\.jpg)]");` This will select anything with a `data-background` attribute matching the regex. You'll have to do this in addition to selecting normal `<img>` tags. Some websites also load all their content dynamically with JavaScript, and Jsoup cannot do JavaScript. Note that writing an algorithm to deal with every possible website structure is _very, very_ hard.

Comment: @JonasCz I want to be able to select anything having *any* attribute that ends with an image file extension. Some of the images are shows with data-background, some with the form of style="background:url(http://cdn.fansided.com/tmpimg/bleacher-report-229-22831.jpg", etc.

Comment: Apparently, this is not possible. Looking at [the docs](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html), you need to give it  the name of the attribute when selecting by regex based on the value of that aqttribute. As a workaround, you could iterate through _all_ elements and their attributes, and check if the value of the attribute matches your regex.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://fansided.com/").userAgent("Mozilla").get();
Elements select = doc.select("[data-background],[style~=background:url]");
```

It will get any element which contains the "data-background" or "style=background:url..." attribute.